# Use academic degrees in thesis acknowledgments

Tags: thesis, degree, acknowledgement

In theses, students typically write acknowledgments thanking their supervisor, co-supervisor, other advisors, etc.

Maybe everyone can just do it at will, but is there any best practice, if academic degrees should be used in the acknowledgements?

Comment: Only if you're in Germany, the land of Prof. Dr. Drs. :)

Comment: If a person helps your research a lot, but he does not have any academic degree, what are you going to say in the acknowledgements?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: i am in austria :/ also the land of degrees... however, i think i will omit it in my thesis. it's just much more readable...

Comment: @scaaahu: in that case i (obviously) will just mention the name.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I think it depends on your subject. Social Sciences usually omit the titles. So my guess for the OP is that s/he should reflect what is usually is done in his/her field.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Not just Germany, the whole central Europe (at least the whole former Austria-Hungary). And remember the prevalence of dottore in Italy. I wouldn't dare to omit them in the Czech Republic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the ones I have seen, they are mostly omitted, but my guess is that this is pretty country and field dependent. You should look at other thesis published in your department, and see if they include them.

Once you know what the norm is, do as you wish. Acknowledgements are the part of your thesis that is *most yours*, and you should write whatever feels right.

Answer (score 1):

The best course of action, as this depends a lot on local (country, area, university, maybe even department) customs, is to go to the library and check a few (more or less recent) theses in your area or closely related ones. Perhaps ask the librarians, they are people trained in much more than storing books. Ask some trusted faculty.